# The project type is not supported by this installation in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I'm trying to create a Windows JavaScript app. Every time I do, i get this error:

```
The project file 'C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Local\Temp\qugu4hsq.ibc\Temp\Test.jsproj' cannot be opened.

The project type is not supported by this installation
```

I've looked up a solution, and it involves editing the jsproj file, but in `source/repos/test`, only the `.vs`, `Test`, and `Test.sln` files/folders exist.

I've looked in the temporary folder, and `qugu4hsq.ibc` doesn't exist. Is it because the Windows Universal C# apps require I upgrade to windows 10 to use?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

See this:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/159626/jsproj-cannot-be-opened-project-type-not-supported.html

Specifically:
It's working for me now. To fix, I had to uninstall the "Universal Windows Platform development" workload. And then reinstall it. Then in the individual components, I had to manually make sure that all the Windows 10 SDKs were checked.

Good luck

Comment: It's what I feared. I have to upgrade to Windows 10.